# How do you print hexadecimal digits to a Perl string?

Tags: perl, string

I have three integers:

```
($r, $g, $b) = (255, 128, 0);
```

I would like to print a string like:

```
"#FF8000"
```

using those variables.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
my $rgb = sprintf '#%02X%02X%02X', $r, $g, $b;
```

See [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) and [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html), to get the hexadecimal string.

```
my $rgb = '#' . uc unpack 'H6', pack 'C3', $r, $g, $b;
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm more comfortable with the C-like syntax, but thanks for the other perspective.